# Match string not followed by another string

Tags: php, regex, string, url, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match a string. For example, in the following strings, first should match, the second should not.

```
/users/akinuri/
/users/akinuri/asd/
```

I've tried a negative lookahead, but it didn't work. Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

```
if (preg_match("/\/users\/.*?\/(?!.*\/)/", "/users/akinuri/asd/")) {
    echo "match";
}
```

---

I'm experimenting (trying to create a route system). Right now, I'm just trying to determine if the requested uri is valid. If a visitor requests the second string, it should return false and I'll return a not found page. For example, test this on SO. The second url returns a not found page.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202732/akinuri/
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202732/akinuri/asdasd
```

---

So, can I do this check using regex? If so, how? What am I doing wrong?

Or should I split the text and then do further checks? This seems a bit redundant.

Comment: You can use this regex: `'~^/users/[^/]+/?$~'`

Comment: @anubhava I'd love if you could elaborate on this and post it as an answer. I tested this and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a lookahead for this. You can use a negated character class `[^/]+` to match 1+ of any character except `/`. You also need to use anchors in regex to make sure you match complete input.

For PHP code, you can use this regex:

```
'~^/users/[^/]+/?$~'
```

Note that `/?$` makes trailing slash an optional match.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l41u4s/1)

Comment: Woot! Implemented this in the actual code and it worked =)